# Как подключить виртуальную машину к виртуальному микротику?

Tags: linux, mikrotik, виртуализация

В virtualbox поднял две виртуалки
1. RouterOS с двумя сетевыми адаптерами.
2. Ubuntu с одним сетевым адаптером.
В настройках машины с микротиком указал сетевой мост и выбрал интерфейс. На самом микротике на интерфейс ether1 повесил dhcp-client. Все работает, микротик в интернет выходит. Как подключить виртуалку с ubuntu к интерфейсу ether2 микротика? Нужно чтобы виртуалка ходила в интернет через виртуальный микротик, а не через хост машину.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите в настройках нужных сетевых адаптеров (второго адаптера для виртуалки микротика и единственного для виртуалки ubuntu) тип подключения `Внутренняя сеть` (`Internal Network`) и впишите в поле имени сети что-нибудь одинаковое на обеих виртуалках, например `intnet`. С точки зрения виртуальных машин все адаптеры подключенные с одноимённой внутренней сети окажутся подключены через общий коммутатор.